# PDTSimpleCalendar set RangeCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

In My iOs App that developed By the Other Developer and set the SimpleCalender.
But Now i want to set the RangeCalendar instead of the SimpleCalender.
But, I don't know how to do this.I have no more Experience.
Other Developer Code is Like,

DatePickerViewController.h file,

```
@interface DatePickerViewController : PDTSimpleCalendarViewController{
}
```

DatePickerViewController is simple view controller.

And in DatePickerViewController.m File,

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setDelegate:self];
self.weekdayHeaderEnabled = YES;
self.weekdayTextType = PDTSimpleCalendarViewWeekdayTextTypeShort;
[[PDTSimpleCalendarViewCell appearance] setCircleSelectedColor:[UIColor defaultColor]];
[[PDTSimpleCalendarViewHeader appearance] setTextColor:[UIColor defaultColor]];
}
```

PDTSimpleCalender Demo [Link](https://github.com/jivesoftware/PDTSimpleCalendar),

So, Please Guide me and Help me where i set and where i change in code For set RangeCalendar ?